# Including Django templates in an arbitrary order

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I'm using separate template files to create "widgets" - HTML snippets that are displayed in a grid layout on the page. The main template includes the widget templates like this:

```
{% include "myapp/widgetA.html" %}
{% include "myapp/widgetB.html" %}
{% include "myapp/widgetC.html" %}
{% include "myapp/widgetD.html" %}
```

This works fine, but I want the user to be able to change the order that the widgets appear in. I will have the user's preferred ordering stored in a tuple, eg: `('widgetC', 'widgetB', 'widgetA', 'widgetD')`

How can I handle this in the template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate over the tuple in the template:

```
{% for widget in my_widgets %}
    {% include widget %}
{% endfor %}
```

where `my_widgets = ('myapp/widgetC.html', 'myapp/widgetB.html', 'myapp/widgetA.html', 'myapp/widgetD.html')` in your view.